# Intercept specific column data inside the SQL-TDS protocol?

Tags: sql-server, freetds

From what I understand, the real TDS protocol implementation is proprietary to Microsoft. I do see that there is another library, http://freetds.schemamania.org/.

If we had to intercept, transform all the data belonging to a particular column (name or type) at the TDS level, what are good hook points? Interception would be for reads AND writes. Since we'd like to do this irrespective of query structure, we're scanning for hook points that are general enough to work across all/most scenarios.

Background:
The transformation for special columns isn't specific to one application itself but across an entire suite of myriad applications using SQL Server (i.e. TDS). We aren't convinced the TDS layer is the best layer but are reviewing the engineering feasibility/practicality.